# Using reserved words in queries that can run on different database servers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have used backticks (`) in some SELECT queries to escape fields such as 'first-name'. This will work on MySQL. These queries are run through a DBO class in a php application and I would like the application to be able to use other database servers, such as MSSQL and Posgres.

What is the best approach for allowing problematic field names to be used across all of these database servers? I was thinking of taking the fields as an array and quoting them with the escaping character that is appropriate to each.

[EDIT]
To clarify: I am building a tool that will be used to map configurations stored within the php application to the fields of an external database. I wanted to escape these as a precaution because I have no idea what field names will actually be mapped to and used within the queries.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard way to escape reserved words across DB vendors.  You could change your column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-DBMS mechanism (as defined in SQL-92 and other standards) is using double-quoted delimited identifiers. According to [this reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Data_structure_definition/Delimited_identifiers) it's widely supported.

It's worth nothing that MySQL allows to [enable/disable this syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) so you still need to ensure that session settings are correct before issuing any query.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple: do not use reserved words as identifiers. It makes the code more difficult to read anyways.

If you really *need* to use such words (as in "there is some obscure reason beyond your control"), you can just prefix all your identifiers by an arbitrary character, such as `_` for example.

Comment: I would probably use the `_` as a suffix rather than a prefix so the table names could be "properly" sorted e.g. in a GUI tool. But that is mainly personal taste...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses backticks (`) by default, but can be configured to support proper ANSI quoting.

IMO: If you're connecting to MySQL, set it to ANSI mode, and while you're at it enable every STRICT option it has. It becomes much easier to write code that's portable against it then.

Of course, the best option has to be not using reserved words, but the list of reserved words can change over time so rigorous quoting isn't such a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of escaping is not to use field names that need escaping.

If you still have to use escaping - use `"`. It is the standard one (defined by ANSI SQL).

Postgres and Oracle understand `"` escaping. But i do not know about MSSQL an MySQL.

Comment: Microsoft and MySQL do support the standard quoting as well - they just need to be configured properly (i.e. to be ANSI compliant).